# How do I get the value of OpenSSL._util.lib.X509_verify_cert_error_string as a python string

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I am trying to print out the error that is input to the certificate verification callback function[I am using pyopenssl]:

```
def verify_cb(context, certificate, errornum, depth, ok):
       if (lib.X509_V_OK == errornum):
           print lib.X509_verify_cert_error_string(errornum)
```

I thought the above code would print `ok`.  However it returns `<cdata 'char *' 0x7fff8b400f0f>`. Debugging this in pdb I get the following:

```
(Pdb) lp=lib.X509_verify_cert_error_string(errnum)
(Pdb) type(lp)
<type '_cffi_backend.CData'>
(Pdb) lp[0]
'o'
(Pdb) lp[1]
'k'
(Pdb) lp[2]
'\x00'
```

Does anyone know how I can get the value of this as a python string other that iterating through this till I get a `\x00` character? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The following gets it to work:

```
from OpenSSL._util import ffi
ffi.string(lib.X509_verify_cert_error_string(errornum))
```